# Populating a Grid with Partial SQL Query Results

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ado.net

I was wondering if there is a way for me to populate a grid with rows that are already retrieved by the SQL query i am executing before query execution finishes. This is because i have some pretty time expensive queries that are making users wait for quite a bit before the grid is actually populated with the results. I am using Visual Studio 2012 C# and Microsoft SQL server 2012. 
Note: The query does not contain any aggregate function, so it is possible to retrieve partial results.

Comment: Why don't you try paging?

Comment: When you select a large amount of data in SQL query analyzer, it populates data as soon as it is ready, instead of waiting the entire operation to complete. I need some way using C# to synchronize this data as soon as it is ready in the actual database query. Paging would work but it is not what I am looking for. I need the grid to be automatically populated in Sync with the data base.

Comment: If you use an unbound grid you can doing the paging out of view of the user. I'm guessing that is what the Query Analyzer does.

Comment: The idea is not to buffer a number of rows to a grid, rather it is to stream all available rows to the grid automatically. If have searched for quite some time now, and am yet to stumble into an answer. Paging technique was a nice idea, just not what i am looking for.